# Browsing through previous-compilation errors during a new compilation?

Tags: c++, emacs, ide, compilation

How to setup emacs so that I can browse through previous-compilation errors during new compilation?

Two things don't work for me:

1. M-g M-g (next-error) function is not working when second compilation is in-progress.
2. I have my emacs split into 5 uneven windows (split-windows-horizontally), the compilation "window" is double the size (dbl monitor setup). When I launch compilation it always appeared in the last double compilation window. Now it opens a new window for itself.

Comment: Considering it's programmable, the answer is yes.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly which details the current answers are lacking?

Comment: @Francesco - Forgot to add explanation what is not working - added in comments to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which seems to fulfill all your requirements:

- the `*compilation-old*` buffer always stays in the same window
- `next-error` does not break
- all successive compilation outputs are appended at the end of `*compilation-old*` when the compilation process terminates

```lisp
(defun my-compilation-finish-function (buffer msg)
  ;; Don't do anything if we are in a derived mode
  (when (with-current-buffer buffer (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode))

    ;; Insert the last compilation output at the end of *compilation-old*
    (if (get-buffer "*compilation-old*")
        (with-current-buffer "*compilation-old*"
          (save-excursion
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (insert-buffer buffer)))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (rename-buffer "*compilation-old*")))))

(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'my-compilation-finish-function)



(defadvice compile (around my-compile-show-old activate)
  "Show the *compilation-old* buffer after starting the compilation"
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
    (when (get-buffer "*compilation-old*")
      (pop-to-buffer "*compilation-old*")
      (switch-to-buffer "*compilation*"))
    ad-do-it
    (when (get-buffer "*compilation-old*")
      (switch-to-buffer "*compilation-old*")
      (pop-to-buffer buffer))))
```

Comment: 2 things don't work for me: 1. M-g M-g (nex-error) function is not working when second compilation is in-progress. 2. I have my emacs split into 5 uneven windows (split-windows-horizontally), the compilation "window" is double the size (dbl moniotr setup). When I launch compilation it always appeared in the last double compilation window. Now it oppens new window for itself.

Comment: As for problem 1, have you tried using `next-error` in the way described in its inline help?  First run `next-error` in the compilation buffer which you want to use as source (`*compilation-old*` in your case), then all successive invocations of `next-error` will use this buffer.

Comment: For problem 2, I don't understand which buffer you would like to see in the double-sized window; the old one or the running one?

Comment: 1. still persists even if I run next-error in old-compilation for the first time. (can you test it on your machine? makefile with sleep inside + corrupted file to compile should be enough)

Comment: As of 2. I would like to see old compilation to a point when new compilation finishes. The I want to see new one (possible named old-compilation).

Comment: Alternatively I would be most happy with concatenation of new compilation outout to *compilation* and if possible, when compile finishes, remove old prefix of the *compile* buffer.

Comment: I'va tried problem 1 and it seems to work for me. After using `next-error` in the `*compilation-old*` buffer the first time, all following errors are taken from there.

Comment: I've completely rewritten the answer; the proposed solution now seems to fulfill all your requirements, if I understood them correctly.

Comment: I will try it first thing tommorow. Thank you for trying! BTW have you considered one-buffer approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19845/discussion-between-francesco-and-lukasz-lew)

Answer (score 2):

Putting the following in your init file will rename the compilation buffer to `*compilation-old*` when the compile command terminates.

Please note that this will not work if you run the new compilation process from the old compilation buffer (since `compile` will in this case reuse the buffer instead of creating a new one)

```lisp
(defun my-rename-compilation-buffer (buffer message)
  ;; Don't do anything if we are in a derived mode
  (when (with-current-buffer buffer (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode))
    (let* ((old-compilation-buffer-name "*compilation-old*")
           (old-compilation-buffer (get-buffer old-compilation-buffer-name)))

      ;; Kill old compilation buffer if necessary
      (when old-compilation-buffer
        (kill-buffer old-compilation-buffer))

      ;; Rename the current compilation buffer
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (rename-buffer old-compilation-buffer-name)))))

(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'my-rename-compilation-buffer)
```

Comment: Still the same problem: 1. (next-error) uses compilation errors only in new window. Even if I execute (next-error) from the second old-compilation buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a Kludge, but try this:

Before starting the new compilation, save (write, C-x C-w) the current compilation buffer to a file.  If the buffer for the new file looses it "compilation-mode" setting, simply turn compilation-mode back on (M-x compilation-mode).

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach. But I can't do it manually. Moreover, when new compilation finishes I would like it to overwrite the old error list.  MAybe we could modify compile command to compile to some temporary buffer and move it to \*compilation\* when finished?